# How to get the dates when the DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and FREEPROCCACHE executed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server can we get the time when the SQL Server service was last restarted?

And how to get the date when the `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and `FREEPROCCACHE` last executed?

Comment: The question would be why would anyone without sufficient knowledge and permissions be running those in Production?

Comment: THIS is NOT the answer of  my QUESTION. 

*I think your answer will be same for "if any rows delete from table from which user then to identify the  deleted the rows from which user is "The question would be why would anyone without sufficient knowledge and permissions be running those in Production?"


I want solution, not the suggestion.
if you have not then please ...

by the way thanks "Paweł Dyl"

Comment: woa! steady fella!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran `dbcc freeproccache` and below is captured in my error log..

> SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Object Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.
>
> SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'SQL Plans' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.
>
> SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of cachestore flush for the 'Bound Trees' cachestore (part of plan cache) due to 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' or 'DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE' operations.

But the same can't be said for all DBCC commands.**Most** of them log details into errorlog/eventvwr.For Example `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` won't write any info ..

The only way to get know which commands are run is through auditing or extended events..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to get that information. However, you can use Extended Events and capture all queries with `%DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS%` in sql_text.